# Keep Lines Containing

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am creating a "Keep Lines containing" project. I almost completed this task. But "Search Lines for" is working only 1 line. Multiple "Search
Lines for" is not working. I need "Search Lines for" in multiple lines.
All used HTML, CSS & javascript codes are here

I created a Codepen page for it. Please check : https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/LYGQyqr

```js
function loadfile(fileid, loadid) {
  document.getElementById(loadid).value = 'Loading...';
  setTimeout(function() {
    loadfile2(fileid, loadid)
  }, 1000);
}

function loadfile2(fileid, loadid) {
  if (!window.FileReader) {
    document.getElementById(loadid).value = 'Your browser does not support HTML5 "FileReader" function required to open a file.';
  } else {
    fileis = document.getElementById(fileid).files[0];
    var fileredr = new FileReader();
    fileredr.onload = function(fle) {
      var filecont = fle.target.result;
      document.getElementById(loadid).value = filecont;
    }
    fileredr.readAsText(fileis);
  }
}

function savefile(saveasid, saveid) {
  if (!window.Blob) {
    alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 "Blob" function required to save a file.');
  } else {
    var txtwrt = document.getElementById(saveid).value;
    if (document.getElementById('dos').checked == true) txtwrt = txtwrt.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
    var textblob = new Blob([txtwrt], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    var saveas = document.getElementById(saveasid).value;
    var dwnlnk = document.createElement('a');
    dwnlnk.download = saveas;
    dwnlnk.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
      dwnlnk.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textblob);
    } else {
      dwnlnk.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textblob);
      dwnlnk.onclick = destce;
      dwnlnk.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(dwnlnk);
    }
    dwnlnk.click();
  }
}

function destce(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function cleartext() {
  document.getElementById('input_output').value = '';
  document.getElementById('removed').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('removed_box').value = '';
}

function SelectAll(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
  document.getElementById(id).select();
}

var fieldnum = 0;
var fieldtype = '';
var cacherem = 'no';
var enableregex = 'no';

function makeregexp() {
  var regexpoutarr = new Array();
  for (var x = 0; x < (fieldnum + 1); x++) {
    regexpoutarr[x] = document.getElementById('addfield' + x).value.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
  }
  var regexpout = '';
  if (fieldtype == 'AND') regexpout = '((?=.*' + regexpoutarr.join(')(?=.*') + ').*)';
  if (fieldtype == 'OR') regexpout = '(' + regexpoutarr.join('|') + ')';
  if (fieldtype == '') regexpout = document.getElementById('addfield0').value.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
  return regexpout;
}

function removelines(whatlines) {
  var textin = document.getElementById('input_output').value.replace(/\r/g, '');
  var toremove = makeregexp();
  var textinarr = textin.split('\n');
  var textinarrcnt = textinarr.length;
  var textoutarr = new Array();
  var textoutarrcnt = 0;
  var linesremovedcnt = 0;
  var casen = 'i';
  if (document.getElementById('case_sen').checked == true) casen = '';
  if (enableregex == 'yes') toremove = document.getElementById('addfield0').value;
  else toremove = makeregexp();
  var killfun = 'no';
  try {
    var toremoveregx = new RegExp(toremove, casen);
  } catch (err) {
    alert('Something is incorrect (' + err + ') within your regular expression.\nBe sure special characters .*+?^=!:${}()|\\ used as literals have been escaped with a backslash.');
    killfun = 'yes';
  }
  if (killfun == 'no') {
    if (whatlines == 'containing' && cacherem == 'no') {
      for (var x = 0; x < textinarrcnt; x++) {
        if (toremoveregx.test(textinarr[x]) == false) {
          textoutarr[textoutarrcnt] = textinarr[x];
          textoutarrcnt++;
        } else linesremovedcnt++;
      }
    }
    if (whatlines == 'notcontaining' && cacherem == 'no') {
      for (var x = 0; x < textinarrcnt; x++) {
        if (toremoveregx.test(textinarr[x]) == true) {
          textoutarr[textoutarrcnt] = textinarr[x];
          textoutarrcnt++;
        } else linesremovedcnt++;
      }
    }
    var removedcachearr = new Array();
    if (whatlines == 'containing' && cacherem == 'yes') {
      for (var x = 0; x < textinarrcnt; x++) {
        if (toremoveregx.test(textinarr[x]) == false) {
          textoutarr[textoutarrcnt] = textinarr[x];
          textoutarrcnt++;
        } else {
          removedcachearr[linesremovedcnt] = textinarr[x];
          linesremovedcnt++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (whatlines == 'notcontaining' && cacherem == 'yes') {
      for (var x = 0; x < textinarrcnt; x++) {
        if (toremoveregx.test(textinarr[x]) == true) {
          textoutarr[textoutarrcnt] = textinarr[x];
          textoutarrcnt++;
        } else {
          removedcachearr[linesremovedcnt] = textinarr[x];
          linesremovedcnt++;
        }
      }
    }
    var textout = textoutarr.join('\n');
    document.getElementById('input_output').value = textout;
    if (cacherem == 'yes') {
      var removedcache = removedcachearr.join('\n');
      document.getElementById('removed_box').value = removedcache;
    }
    document.getElementById('removed').innerHTML = '' + linesremovedcnt + ' removed / ' + textoutarrcnt + ' remain.';
  }
}

function addfield(field) {
  if (field == 'reset') {
    document.getElementById('inputfields').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="addfield0" value="" style="width:100%;" />'
    document.getElementById('andbttn').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('orbttn').style.display = 'inline-block';
    fieldnum = 0;
    fieldtype = '';
  } else {
    fieldnum++;
    if (fieldnum == 1) {
      if (field == 'andfield') {
        document.getElementById('orbttn').style.display = 'none';
        fieldtype = 'AND';
      } else {
        fieldtype = 'OR';
        document.getElementById('andbttn').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    var newfield = fieldtype + '<input type="text" id="addfield' + fieldnum + '" value="" style="width:100%;" />';
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = newfield;
    document.getElementById('inputfields').appendChild(newdiv);
  }
  resizepage();
}

function disrem() {
  var chkedstate = document.getElementById('dremoved').checked;
  if (chkedstate == true) {
    document.getElementById('removed_box').style.display = 'inline-block';
    cacherem = 'yes';
  } else {
    cacherem = 'no';
    document.getElementById('removed_box').value = '';
    document.getElementById('removed_box').style.display = 'none';
  }
  resizepage();
}

function selectele(eleid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(eleid));
    range.select();
  } else {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(eleid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
}

function regexsrch() {
  var chkedstate = document.getElementById('regex_srch').checked;
  if (chkedstate == true) {
    addfield('reset');
    enableregex = 'yes';
    document.getElementById('addfielddiv').innerHTML =
      '<div style="padding:3px 0px 3px 0px;"><input type="checkbox" id="regex_srch" onclick="regexsrch();" CHECKED />Enable regular expression search. ' +
      'Use <span id="catordog" style="color:#990000;" onclick="selectele(this.id)">(cat|dog|bird)</span> for cat OR dog OR bird. Use <span id="catanddog" style="color:#990000;" onclick="selectele(this.id)">((?=.*cat)(?=.*dog)(?=.*bird).*)</span> for cat AND dog AND bird. ' +
      'Remember to escape special characters .*+?^=!:${}()|\\ with a backslash when used as literals within a regular expression. Use the <a target="_blank" href="" style="color:#0000FF;">Escape Literal Characters</a> tool. ' +
      'Learn more about regular expressions visit <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions" style="color:#0000FF;">developer.mozilla.org</a>.</div>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('addfield0').value = '';
    enableregex = 'no';
    document.getElementById('addfielddiv').innerHTML =
      'Add <input type="button" id="andbttn" value="AND" onClick="addfield(\'andfield\');" /> ' +
      '<input type="button" id="orbttn" value="OR" onClick="addfield(\'orfield\');" /> search field. ' +
      '<input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="addfield(\'reset\');" /> ' +
      '<input type="checkbox" id="regex_srch" onclick="regexsrch();" />Enable regular expression search.';
  }
  resizepage();
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.se-for {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #b93207;
  padding-top: 54px;
}

.contentt,
.wordd {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.contentt {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wordd {
  height: 99px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

input[type='radio'] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type='text'] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

input[type='button'] {
  width: auto;
  margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #b93207;
  color: #fff;
  border: #b93207;
}

input[type='button']:hover {
  color: #f9f900;
}

input[type='button']:hover {}

input[type='file'] {
  width: 92px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -92px;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='file']::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  padding: 0px;
}

.buttonz {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #E1E1D2;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.navcat {
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

div.navdiv {
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 18px 10px 13px 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

a.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000000;
}

#toolpadding {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#tool {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool">
  <div id="toolpadding">
    <div id="topdiv">
      <div class="se-for">Search lines for:</div>
      <div id="inputfields" style="padding-top:4px;">
        <textarea type="text" id="addfield0" class="wordd">Three</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonz">
        <input type="button" value="Keep Lines Containing" onClick="if(document.getElementById('addfield0').value!='') {removelines('notcontaining');}" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="case_sen" />Case sensitive.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middiv" style="height:120px;">
      <textarea id="input_output" class="contentt" wrap="off">
    One One One One One One One One One One One One One One One
    Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three
    Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two
    Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two
    Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three
    Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three
    Four Four Four Four Four Four Four Four Four Four Four Four
    Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five
    Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three
    Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five Five
    Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three Three
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="btmdiv">
      <textarea id="removed_box" rows="4" style="display:none; width:100%; margin-top:10px;" wrap="off">
        Removed Line Box - Removed/extracted lines will display here.</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console errors

Comment: You likely meant `document.getElementById('removed_box').value = ` instead of `document.getElementById('removed').innerHTML =`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Please check here its working https://codepen.io/coderco/pen/LYGQyqr

Comment: Here I put "Search lines for:" is "Three". I want to add muliple.

Comment: So add the removed field to the code and make a [mcve] - you have a LOT of irrelevant code here

Comment: I am not a developer. My developer has given me work like this. he don't know anything more. Could you create a working Codepen page ?  & share me url..

Comment: I added "removed" element and the logic for having multiple words - https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/rNxJwJK the other logic needs to be looked at. I do not feel like doing that. It is a mess

Comment: I think you didnt understood what I mean .. Please visit this site https://miniwebtool.com/remove-lines-containing See screenshot https://prnt.sc/tc3wzc In this website we can not put more than 1 line in the "Containing what?" column. I am looking for multiple lines in the "Containing what?"  column

Comment: Oh. Ok. I put the lines in the Search lines for

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps. Too much like work. Ask your developer please